# How to set language in facebook apprequest method

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have used FB.ui - apprequests method. Everything is working fine. My app for french people. 
So, how to change the language using any parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the JS SDK with the correct locale, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/gettingstarted/#params

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. I have faced a localization problem.

From the beginning, I have used https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js script.

Based on my needs, I have used https://connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js.

Issue fixed..Thanks CBroe. :)